# Let $I,J,K$ ideals of ring R. Prove that $I+JK \subseteq (I+J)(I+K)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I,J,K$ ideals of ring R. Prove that $I+JK \subseteq (I+J)(I+K)$

**Comments:** This is something I need to solve an exercise. Previously tasted the ring I'm working $IJ = I \cap J$ should the need arise.

I'm trying to take $a \in I+JK$ and show including, but not out.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Can you show that $I+JK \subset (I+J) \cap (I+K)$?

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem, thank you.